# laptop reboots on resume with installed 16.04, yet suspend on live cd works fine

Tags: 16.04, resume

My laptop (Dell M3800, similar to XPS-15 in design), with ubuntu 16.04 installed, reboots instead of waking up from suspend to ram.

*However, suspend/resume with live-cd 16.04 works perfectly.*

What is the difference between the two? My installed ubuntu uses cryptsetup-based encrypted swap/root/home. That's all. This should be a concern for hibernate, but afaik it shouldn't be for suspend to ram.

If I compare /var/log/pm-suspend on both cases, I only see very few differences, which I am not sure will help. dmesg doesn't show any error. The system goes to suspend state, but when resuming, it just reboots.

No need to say I'm pretty frustrated about this ;-)

[EDIT, Aug 27 2016] So, after looking into it, it seems that suspend works if a USB key is plugged in, no matter what that key contains. So I 'fixed' my problem by plugging in a USB key before going to suspend, and then resume works as expected.

I got the clue from the fact that suspend works when using the ubuntu live CD, but not when using the installed version. Any clue about this???